# Can the filename in the pycharm run line bar be displayed in multiple lines

Tags: python, pycharm

If the run column runs a lot of Py files, the multiple py files will fold up (Figure 1), and you must click on the right little arrow (Figure 2) to show the remaining files,how to set up the running py files to display multiple lines instead of folding them up?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. Can you take a better photo?

Comment: I've changed my question and please help me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible in PyCharm.

Comment: Do you have a better running and multi tasking editor?

Comment: I am not aware of any better.